# Possible compiler bug in MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The following code compiles with gcc and clang (and many other C++11 compilers)

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int datatype;

template <typename T>
struct to_datatype {};

template <>
struct to_datatype<int16_t> {
  static constexpr datatype value = 1;
};

template <typename T>
class data {
 public:
  data(datatype dt = to_datatype<T>::value) {}
};

int main() {
  data<char> d{to_datatype<int16_t>::value};
}
```

when compile with (almost) latest MSVC

```
> cl .\test.cpp /std:c++latest /permissive-
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28314 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
.\test.cpp(16): error C2039: 'value': is not a member of 'to_datatype<T>'
        with
        [
            T=char
        ]
.\test.cpp(16): note: see declaration of 'to_datatype<T>'
        with
        [
            T=char
        ]
.\test.cpp(20): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'data<char>' being compiled
```

Is this a bug of MSVC? If yes, which term in C++ standard best describe it?

If you replace part of the code with

```
template <typename T>
class data {
 public:
  data(datatype dt) {}
  data() : data(to_datatype<T>::value) {}
};
```

it compiles smoothly anyway.

Comment: This one-liner might explain the differences. See what your compilers return for `std::is_same_v<char, int8_t>`. My guess would be that it is implementation defined whether int8_t is the same as char, but one would need to check documentation.

Comment: Looks like it may in fact be a bug. [This issue](https://github.com/boostorg/proto/issues/18) was opened recently and there have been several other reports.

Comment: @alteredinstance I don't see how that issue relates to this question, or how your previous link does, for that matter. Did you just copy the first link google gives for this error message? The error message is very generic and can appear in many different (legitimate) situations.

Comment: @walnut [Line 231 of the code mentioned in the issue](https://github.com/boostorg/proto/blob/develop/include/boost/proto/generate.hpp) has a defunct link to an MSVC issue with aggregate initialization, the same thing OP's code is doing. It just so happens that the boost library has recently run into a similar issue with using `value` in an aggregate type with MSVC

Comment: @alteredinstance OP is not doing any aggregate initialization. `data` is not an aggregate type since it has a user-provided constructor. Going by the link's name, the referenced issue is a codegen issue, not frontend issue that would result in a compilation error like this here. I also already posted an answer to this question below. The issue here is whether or not the default argument should be instantiated. If it is instantiated, then the error message is correct. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Similar issue - "fixed" - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/86696/vc-2017-default-arguments-of-member-function-are-m.html. But it looks like its still broken.

Comment: and a new bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/871304/vc-2019-default-arguments-of-member-function-are-m.html

Comment: `data` is not an aggregate type, `to_datatype` is though, and is the one experiencing the issue.

Comment: @marcinj The first report and the title of your new one are slightly different from the issue here. As mentioned in the question, the error doesn't happen when the class is implicitly instantiated, but only if the member function with the default argument is used in a call (which as I state in my answer I don't believe should cause default argument instantiation if the default argument is not used by the call).

Comment: @alteredinstance `to_datatype` is aggregate, but nowhere in the code is an instance of that type created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say MSVC is wrong not to accept the code.

According to [[dcl.fct.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.default#5) of the C++17 standard final draft, name lookup in default arguments of a member function of a class template is done according to the rules in [temp.inst].

According to [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2) implicit instantiation of a class template does not cause instantiation of default arguments of member functions and according to [[temp.inst]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4) a default argument for a member function of a (non-explicit specialization of a) class template is instantiated when it is used by a call.

There is no call using the default argument `to_datatype<T>::value` in your code and so it should not be instantiated. Therefore there shouldn't be an error about lookup of `value` in `to_datatype<char>` failing.

(The relevant sections in the C++11 standard final draft have equivalent wording, except for numbering, see [[decl.fct.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default#5), [[temp.inst]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.inst#1) and [[temp.inst]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.inst#3) instead.)